# Does the newest version of rpy2 support python 3.6.9?

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2

Our team here recently switched to using conda and, in the process, has upgraded all the python libraries and moved us to python 3.6.9. We also have users that code in R. As such, our team has enabled us to use R and python simultaneously in Jupyter Notebooks. This has been done using rpy2 (running 2.9.4 at the moment) and leveraging cell or line magics.

For example, we might have some python dataframe that we want to plot using ggplot2 in R. Previously, we were able to use `%Rpush` and `%Rpull` to move dataframe objects between languages.

With this upgrade, these functions are no longer returning the appropriate object but instead are returning this: `<rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector - Python:0x7fc038c85d50 / R:0x5571f1d3b108>`

I don't have an engineering background but am one of the few R users who would like this resolved. When I switch the kernel of the notebook to python2, the r magics work without issue. However, when I use our python3 kernel (running 3.6.9) it breaks. I checked the rpy2 documentation and it seems it may only support up to 3.5? https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/overview.html

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The developers of `rpy2` say, it is compatible with Python 2.7 and >3.3. Since it is developed on UNIX-like operating systems, so that, running it on Windows can be problematic. If you use Windows 10, you can install WSL and use it to install Jupyter Notebook/lab, R kernel, R Studio.

Comment: The [documentation of rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/interactive.html?highlight=rpush) describes `%Rpush` and `%Rpull` with a capital `R`, could that make a difference? Could also be that you're on a different version of IPython (ipykernel), which presents the returned object differently.

Comment: @RolandWeber sorry, I was just being lazy by not capitalizing them. We are using Rpush and Rpull.

Comment: @swatchai we are on macs, so presumably that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous integration for rpy2 on Travis CI is currently running tests with Python 3.6 and 3.7 on Linux, and whatever is the latest on OSX: https://travis-ci.com/rpy2/rpy2